# Installing Xampp?

Tags: installation, xampp, uninstallation

Do I have to uninstall the previous version first? before updating to the latest one? I am getting errors.

Answer (score 1):

Yes both Xamp and wamp highly recommend you uninstall before installing a newer version.

Answer (score 0):

I normally use the no-install version that just unzips to a directory.  In that case, no, you could just rename the directory and install a new version.

If you're using the installer, though, it's probably best to uninstall.  However, make sure you save your mysql databases and anything else you might want to keep across installs!

Comment: I kept the database and the docs folder, but now my Dreamweaver won't open the server anymore with the new install.

Comment: Which server?  Apache server?  mysql server?